# Multiple lines of user input in to separate lists on Python 3

Tags: python, list, input

I'm trying to write a python program that asks the user to input lines of text or periods. No numbers and no capital letters/special characters. Each line must be the same length. I want to assign each line to its own list so that I can check for valid words. However, I can't figure out how to make each new line assign to a new list. Everything I write overwrites the previous list. When they hit enter on a blank line, the program will check for valid words across and up and down. I can do that part, but I can't get these lists to assign correctly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It will be difficult to help without seeing your code. Please edit your question to include the relevant portions.

Comment: `lists = []; for line in ...: lists.append(line.split())`?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new list every time will be difficult to handle so I suggest you use list of lists.
Here is a code snippet which will store the lines in a list of lists. Traversing will be simple as you can index them. The code is given below

```
count=eval(input("Enter count of lines:")
l=[] #creates a list
i=0
While (i<count):
    s=input("Enter line:")
    l1=s.split()
    l.append(l1)
    i+=1

print(l)
```

Hope this helps!